# How can I display the row values in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have to display row values in Html page using jquery, but did not find any solution.

`

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>My Java Program</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" border="2">
<tr><td>hello</td><td>gaurav</td><td>Present<input type="radio" value="present" name="rad0>">&nbsp;
        Absent<input type="radio" value="absent" name="rad0"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>gaurav</td><td>Present<input type="radio" value="present" name="rad1>">&nbsp;
        Absent<input type="radio" value="absent" name="rad1"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>gaurav</td><td>Present<input type="radio" value="present" name="rad2>">&nbsp;
        Absent<input type="radio" value="absent" name="rad2"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>gaurav</td><td>Present<input type="radio" value="present" name="rad3>">&nbsp;
        Absent<input type="radio" value="absent" name="rad3"/></td></tr>





</table>
<br>
<button id="mark" onclick="mark">Mark</button>
<p id="out">-----</p>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#mark").on("click",function(){


                    var vals="";
                    $('#myTable tr').each(function(){
                        vals+=$(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()+",";
                        vals+=$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()+",";
                        var checked = $(this).find('input:radio:checked').val();
                        vals+=checked;


                    });

                    $('#out').html(vals);



                });


});
            </script>
            </body>
</html>
```

And my output is

> hello,gaurav,undefinedhello,gaurav,undefinedhello,gaurav,undefinedhello,gaurav,undefined

I don't know where i am wrong?

Comment: Just what I'd expect if no radio buttons were checked, and the code seems to find the right values if one *is* checked. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Strongly suggest you take the time to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: Which part of the code is the relevant part?

Comment: The exact code you posted, copied and pasted into a jsFiddle, works just fine when an element is actually selected: https://jsfiddle.net/kx9cd00z/  What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the same name to the radio buttons, and ensure that they are checked (the undefined output is because there isn't any radio button checked).

```
var vals="";

$('#myTable tr').each(function(){
    vals+=$(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()+",";
    vals+=$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()+",";
    var checked = $(this).find('input:radio:checked').val();
    if(checked)
        vals+=checked + "<br />";
    else
        vals+="not checked <br />";
});
```

See this fiddle I've built from your example: https://jsfiddle.net/go7jpp9n/1/